# Dotfuscator + delegate (Func<> )

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, func, dotfuscator

In a class that has been excluded(by namespace) from obfuscation(because it has to be transfered), I have a constructor with this kind of constructor

```
public MyClass<T> (T currentObject, Func<T, int> extrator) : where T : XYZ{}
```

When I call the constructor, I do something like

```
new MyClass(myObject, o=>o.Id)
```

After compilation I saw that a static method has been added when decompilating:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private static int <.ctor>b__b(CurrentObjectClass e)
{
    return e.Id;
}
```

Since it's a method and that my namespace is excluded, I was expecting that this class would not be changed. But after dotfuscator comes on it, I got this:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private static int <.ctor>b__5(CurrentObjectClass e)
{
//Obfuscated code
}
```

Since I use this class between a client and a server, it often happens that the server runs with the release(obfuscated) and the client only in debug, so we want to have this class not obfuscated to allows this class to be exchanged (through .Net remoting).

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: How is the obfuscation affecting remoting? When you make a remote call it's the data in the class that is serialized and sent, not the class itself.

Comment: I got a `SerializationException`: `Cannot get the member '<.ctor>b__5'` on the side where it's called `b__b`(not obfuscated) so I think this is transfered.

Comment: Is the class that calls `new MyClass(myObject, o=>o.Id)` marked as serializable? `MyClass` will have a reference to an instance of this class (as it contains the compiler generated method) so the instance will need to be serialized.

Comment: Yes, the two classes(`MyClass` and the caller) are `Serializable`

Comment: Have you tried excluding this compiler-generated method from renaming?

Comment: I finally found why the issue was happening, nothing to do with the obfuscation finally. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue:

The obfuscation has in fact nothing to do, the issue was caused because the client and the server were not generated in the same build, meaning that the compiler was generating two differents names on each compilation.

I avoided the usage of a delegate type and now it works, even with the obfuscation.

Thank you for your help.